# Salesforce lightning community: How to download a document that is set as fileField of a knowledge record?

Tags: lightning, community, knowledge

I'm working with salesforce knowledge and communities (Customer community, template Napili). On the Knowledge object (__kav) I have an file-field. I need to allow to users of community to access and download the file saved on the knowledge object, on a lightning custom component used on the community.

I followed the approach suggested by the knowledge implementation guide for visualforce,
[knowledge implementation guide page 32](http://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/salesforce_knowledge_implementation_guide.pdf)

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Offer__kav.FileFieldDownload,
Offer__kav.id, ['field'=$ObjectType.Offer__kav.fields.my_file__Body__s.name])}">Click
me</apex:outputLink>
```

and tried to use the link generated by this approach. Unfortunately, appear to don't be useful for community, in fact the link generated in this way is not usable in community, because following the link salesforce redirect the user to the login page before to give access to the resource.

I'm stuck because I don’t know how make the resource available in community.

If anyone has insights is welcome.

Thanks,
Klodjan

Comment: Seems really weird that this question got an up vote.

Comment: @MartinLezer i edited the description, and tried to give more context and details of the use case. Sorry, yesterday I was frustrated and tiered, and this was the cause of a bad question. I hope you don't blame too much me. While the upvote comes from a friend that tried just to help me :D

Answer (score 0):

the night brings counsel, or make me less strupid!! Who knows.
I just went to check how works the Article Content component (the standard one for community) and i found that the url to access the resource from the community is slightly different. Infact the url used by article content component is built like:

```
[community base url]+'/servlet/fileField?entityId='+[knowledge articleid]+'&field='+[my_field__Body__s]
```

this solved my need.

Hope that can be useful also for others.

Klodjan